Proof that A*M*A' is not invertible
I came across an unknown mathematical theorem in a book about the Kalman filter, but I'm not sure how to prove it.
Let $M\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$ be a covariance matrix (hence symmetric) and $A\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times2}$ be an arbitrary matrix. Then, the matrix $B = A M A^T$ is not invertible.
I think I can somehow prove that the matrix $B$ is not a full rank matrix, but I'm not sure how.

Hint: What do you know about the rank of $A$ and $A^T$? What does this say about their null spaces?

@whpowell96, Oh, I think I know what you mean! The rank of matrices $A$ and $A^T$ can be 2 at most because of their size, so the rank of B can also be up to 2, and it can never be a full rank. Is that what you mean?

Yes. That argument can be made more formal if you wish to prove it
